# Set 2 different list to spinner based on condition

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have 2 `ArrayList` & want to set one of them based on conditions. However, it is not getting set.

Inside `onCreate()` I defined `ArrayAdapter` & one of the lists based on condition. First time it works but next time when I update lists & try to sets again using `notifyDataSetChanged()` then didn't work & spinner shows blank list in DD.

Pseudo code is below

```
list1, list2;
flag = True/False;
arraydapter(context, res, flag ? list1 : list2);

refreshList() {
if (flag)
list1.clear();
else
list2.clear();

addDataInList();
}

addDataInList() {
if (flag)
list1.add(something);
else
list2.add(something);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Nope by notifyDataSetChanged method you can't change list of data, this method is used when in your current list there is any update, but when you totally change list then you need to again set as adapter to listview, or you can use only only on list and then update it and call notify method

Comment: You should show your real code, not your pseudo code. But, a question I already have based on the pseudo code: when is "arraydapter(context, res, flag ? list1 : list2);" executed? Once in the onCreate()? Because if that is the case, the adapter will be empty if not flagged.

Comment: have you tried creating two different adapters then change adapter based on your condition?

Comment: @Vickyexpert Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying list1/ list2 does not modify the list you have passed to array adapter.

You have to set this new data in array adapter before calling notifydatasetchanged() or you need to create new adapter.

I suggest having a function called setData which replaces the list inside arrayadapter and called notifydatasetchanged.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the adapter is only set once. Since the adapter references either `list1` or `list2`, the Spinner contains only blanks when the `flag` flips.

Therefore, only use a single list. I've adapted your pseudo code accordingly:

```
list;
flag = True/False;

onCreate() {
    arraydapter(context, res, list);
}

refreshList() {
    list.clear();

    if (flag)
        list.add(something);      // i.e. list1 contents
    else
        list.add(something_else); // i.e. list2 contents

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```